# rust cargo build hangs in a virtual box using vagrant

Tags: virtualbox, freeze, arch-linux, vagrant, build

Im using vagrant to setup an development environment for a project of mine. However every time I try to build a rust project using cargo, each rustc process which compiles a file freezes and as a result the process is unkillable and the file system not navigatable without freezing the console.

Vagrant uses virtualbox as virtual environment. The guest system uses arch linux. The host system uses arch linux as well.

Already checked things:
The open file maximum is not reached.

Any ideas?

Cheers!